# Windows 7 can see other Windows 7 machines but not Samba Server, all on same workgroup

Tags: windows-7, raspberry-pi, samba, network-shares, workgroup

I have two Windows 7 laptops, call them A and B, and a Raspberry Pi Samba 
server on a home network, all sharing the same Windows workgroup name.  The Pi's name is RPHS.

A and B can see each other (their names appear under Network in Explorer on 
both laptops).

Both A and B can access the Pi if I specify the IP Address in Explorer.

The Pi's name appears in A (under Network) but **not** in B.

On B, if I execute:

```
nbtstat -a RPHS
```

I get 'Host not found'.

(On 'A' RPHS is resolved correctly).

On the troublesome laptop 'B', power management of the network adaptor is disabled and the driver is up-to-date. I'm using wireless networking. Also, the computer browser service is running. I have tried disabling the firewall but it made no difference.

I don't understand Windows networking well enough to debug this.  Should I 
be using NetBios? Should I be using WINS?  If yes/no, how do I 
enable/disable them?

I could try running Wireshark to look for the network broadcasts, but don't really know what I'm looking for.

I would greatly appreciate some help. I am close to pulling my hair out!

Best regards

David

Answer (score 0):

Check your Samba configurations on the PI. Try using all lowercase letters and make sure your using the latest stable version.

Check the hosts file on laptop B to make sure it does not contain any matching entries.

Check the IP range for your wireless and wired networks and make sure they are in the same subnet. (192.168.1.*). Try using DHCP on all the clients wired and wireless if you are not. Make sure your on the same wireless network.

If you have a guest network option they sometimes block samba from communicating between clients.

Comment: Thanks for replying but this hasn't helped. The hosts file is all comments and all machines are on the same subnet. Must admit I didn't try specifying the workgroup in lower case but I am using a recent version of Samba. Didn't understand the last sentence about guest network option,

Comment: Some routers have a guest network setup. You can give guests internet access but it prevents them from accessing your computers

Comment: Running Wireshark on one of the laptops I notice these sequential packet transfers:
 
   1) Laptop –> Pi    BJNP    Scanner command: discover
   2) Pi –> Laptop    ICMP    'Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)'
 
This happens even on a laptop that successfully communicates with the Samba server.
 
Could this indicate a configuration problem? If so, how might I fix it?

Comment: Check your router settings (Firewall section maybe) for an option to block ICMP requests. This setting may not be available or may be in another location depending on your router. Google should help you out there though. If that isint the problem then you should also look at your firewall on the PI. Most likely IP tables. I am not very well versed in using ip tables but there are many great guides around.